# Java Servlet Session Attribute

Tags: session

I am trying to understanding why this is happening.

I am using Tomcat 7 and java.

I created a jsp page that create a session attribute that contains a HashMap and a servlet retrieving the HashMap from the session.

What I don't understand is why if the servlet remove an item from the HashMap but does not perform the setAttribute function, the jsp then retrieve the session attribute and now has one less item from the HashMap.

Here's my example:

JSP:

`Map<Integer, String> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
testMap.put(1, "Apple");
testMap.put(2, "Orange");
request.setAttribute("testMap", testMap);`

`System.out.println("testMap count: " + testMap.size()); // => returns 2`

Servlet:

`Map<Integer, String> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
testMap = (Map<Integer, String>)session.getAttribute("testMap");
testMap.remove(1);`

At this point, I am not using the setAttribute("testMap", testMap) in the servlet, but when my jsp access this testMap in session, the count is 1???

Please help me to understand why.

Thanks

Comment: Q: Why not `Map<Integer, String> testMap = (Map<Integer, String>)session.getAttribute("testMap");`?  And is the value "2" before you do "remove()"?

Comment: you are right, I forgot to enter the cast from session. But the number in jsp is 2 before I call the servlet and when servlet remove an item and returns back to jsp, jsp will now see only 1 item. Taken that the servlet does not use the setAttribute to change the state of the session object.